Can the Clock on iPhone tell me the day of week?
The following screenshot is the Clock app on iPhone with iOS 18.1.
It is not very useful to tell me the time is "Current" and in Cupertino it is "Yesterday".
Is there a way to make it say, Sunday for Taipei, and Saturday for Cupertino?

